# como contar las cantidad de registros existentes en sql

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intenando obtener el conteo de inscripciones por Disciplina por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero con lo que diseñe la de spinning no me sale en el listado ya que no existe una inscripcion

```
    select d.*,COUNT(di.CodDisciplinaTipoInscripcion)CantidadCliente from Disciplina d
inner join DisciplinaTipoInscripcion dt on d.CodDisciplina=dt.CodDisciplina
inner join DetalleInscripcion di on di.CodDisciplinaTipoInscripcion=dt.CodDisciplinaTipoInscripcion
where d.Estado='ACT'
group by d.CodDisciplina,d.NombreDisciplina,d.Descripcion,d.Estado
```

mi diseño de base de datos es
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías usar left join. Quedaría algo así:

```
select d.*,COUNT(di.CodDisciplinaTipoInscripcion)CantidadCliente from Disciplina d
left join DisciplinaTipoInscripcion dt on d.CodDisciplina=dt.CodDisciplina
left join DetalleInscripcion di on di.CodDisciplinaTipoInscripcion=dt.CodDisciplinaTipoInscripcion
where d.Estado='ACT'
group by d.CodDisciplina,d.NombreDisciplina,d.Descripcion,d.Estado
```